# The callstack is a model that describes how functions are processed. Is there a similar model for variable assignment, if statements & loops?

Tags: javascript

This [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ) talks about a callstack that functions get 'pushed onto' and 'popped off' of.
If a method in the stack takes a long time, to complete, it can cause blocking - new DOM rendering pauses and sometimes the rendering actions get backlogged and execute after any lengthy functions have finished executing.

What about things like assigning variables, if statements and loops? Are they not potentially time-consuming operations that could cause blocking as described here? Is there a model for these sorts of operations like there is for functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've misunderstood. Javascript is single-threaded, so everything that happens in client-side JavaScript (excluding web workers) blocks the main thread. That does not include things like IO that occur outside of the JavaScript interpreted code, so fetching data from an API for instance will not block the main thread. But execution of any code you write - variable assignments, functions, loops, expression evaluation, all that - occurs on the same thread that renders the DOM, so long calculations will cause the UI to freeze (again, unless you hand the computations off to a web worker).

So the question of blocking is unrelated to the call stack, which is the way the JS interpreter keeps track of what function is calling what function, so data is returned to the right caller. As for there being a "model" for assignments etc, the question is a bit unclear, but there is something called the "execution context". The execution context is closely related to the call stack in that a new execution context is created whenever a function is called on the stack. The execution context contains all the data the interpreter needs to execute the code within the current function (or top level code, if that's where we are).

You can read more about the details here: https://levelup.gitconnected.com/learn-javascript-fundamentals-scope-context-execution-context-9fe8673b3164

Comment: The last sentence of your first paragraph - *execution of any code you write...occurs on the same thread that renders the DOM*. What thread are you talking about here? Not the JavaScript main-thread that renders the DOM?

Comment: Yes, that same thread @tonitone120. That's why JS blocks the UI. There is no multithreading within a browser window. It's all just one and the same thread.

Comment: (Web-workers aside) the whole browser window is rendered by JavaScript - and therefore the whole rendering can be looked at as occurring on the main-thread? And what does IO stand for in your 2nd sentence?

Comment: No, the whole browser window is not rendered by JS, but the code that does the rendering is executed on the same thread as the JavaScript. IO stands for Input/Output. Usually that will be network stuff in a browser.

Comment: Interesting. As for my question, I know it was a little confusing. But would you mind looking at my comment on Diesel's answer and seeing if what I'm saying is right. If so, it - and your answer - would solve my question and prove to me that all code I write really is part of a function that gets executed in the main stack (with each function having an execution context). (I have a practical knowledge of the execution context, and closures, and I might read the article you linked to get more of a technical understanding as it might help done the line. At the very least I've taken a note of it!

Comment: *the code that does the rendering is executed on the same thread as the JavaScript* - would this rendering code be the things like everything from `domInteractive` to `unload` events?

Answer (score 0):

If you can specifically reference a point in the video, or what it describes, I can be more specific. But I'm not watching a 26 minute video to answer this! But I'll try.

A call stack is the way a javascript interpreter keeps track of where it is. For example, you call function `a`, `a` is pushed to the stack and run. If `a` calls `b`, then `b` is pushed to the stack. If `b` calls `c` then `d`, `c` is pushed to the stack, it completes, it's popped off, and `b` resumes where it was. Then it calls `d` and `d` runs and and returns and is popped off the stack. Then `b` finished, it's popped off the stack, and `a` continues where it was.

The stuff you mentioned, if statements, loops, assigning variables (and their scope) all happen inside functions (but it's more complex, scopes close over values and so forth). So yes, they do cause blocking, but they don't have their own spot on the call stack. You can think of them as the content of what runs on an item in the call stack.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Call_stack

Comment: Just had a thought when you said loops etc. all occur within functions. The video did talk about there being a 'main' function which is actually the file itself. So for example an if statement found on the top level of code belongs in this main function? That would solve the problem. (As a completely side note, does this call stack just take in function declarations - not function expressions?)

Comment: Yes the "main" function is the code that runs at the top level outside of any function declaration. It's really just another function, but doesn't need to be declared as such. I don't understand the "side note". The call stack is used whenever a function of any kind is called - it's necessary so that the interpreter knows where to go back to when the function exits.

Comment: Thanks @seesharper. Last question I wanted to ask was *the code that does the rendering is executed on the same thread as the JavaScript* - would this rendering code be the things like everything from `domInteractive` to `domContentLoaded` to `unload` events?

Comment: No, those are still javascript events. Think about the native code (probably compiled C++) that interprets the CSS and HTML and actually draws the content to the screen. The thread that does all that is also the thread that interprets/executes the javascript code you've written.

Comment: @seesharper ah so it's the opposite way around. The `domInteractive` stuff is JS code, that probably gets done on that JS main thread...but that JS main-thread exists on/is part of a much bigger thread where that native code also exists?

Comment: Exactly. Each browser tab/window has a single thread responsible for all rendering *and* javascript execution.

Comment: @seesharper Is that why slow JS can stop the browser from rendering?